# Generate raw binary from C code in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, kernel

I have been implementing just for fun a simple operating system for x86 architecture from scratch. I implemented the assembly code for the bootloader that loads the kernel from disk and enters in 32-bit mode. The kernel code that is loaded is written in C, so in order to be executed the idea is to generate the raw binary from the C code.

Firstly, I used these commands:

```
$gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -m32

$ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o --oformat binary -m elf_i386
```

However, it didn't generate any binary giving back these errors:

```
kernel.o: In function 'main':
kernel.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to '_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
```

Just for clarity sake, the kernel.c code is:

```
/* kernel.c */

void main ()
{
   char *video_memory = (char *) 0xb8000 ;
   *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

Then I followed this tutorial: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler
to implement my own cross-compiler for my own target. It worked for my purpose, however disassembling with the command `ndisasm` I obtained this code:

```
00000000  55                push ebp
00000001  89E5              mov ebp,esp
00000003  83EC10            sub esp,byte +0x10
00000006  C745FC00800B00    mov dword [ebp-0x4],0xb8000
0000000D  8B45FC            mov eax,[ebp-0x4]
00000010  C60058            mov byte [eax],0x58
00000013  90                nop
00000014  C9                leave
00000015  C3                ret
00000016  0000              add [eax],al
00000018  1400              adc al,0x0
0000001A  0000              add [eax],al
0000001C  0000              add [eax],al
0000001E  0000              add [eax],al
00000020  017A52            add [edx+0x52],edi
00000023  0001              add [ecx],al
00000025  7C08              jl 0x2f
00000027  011B              add [ebx],ebx
00000029  0C04              or al,0x4
0000002B  0488              add al,0x88
0000002D  0100              add [eax],eax
0000002F  001C00            add [eax+eax],bl
00000032  0000              add [eax],al
00000034  1C00              sbb al,0x0
00000036  0000              add [eax],al
00000038  C8FFFFFF          enter 0xffff,0xff
0000003C  16                push ss
0000003D  0000              add [eax],al
0000003F  0000              add [eax],al
00000041  41                inc ecx
00000042  0E                push cs
00000043  088502420D05      or [ebp+0x50d4202],al
00000049  52                push edx
0000004A  C50C04            lds ecx,[esp+eax]
0000004D  0400              add al,0x0
0000004F  00                db 0x00
```

As you can see, the first 9 rows (except for the NOP that I don't know why it is inserted) are the assembly translation of my main function. From 10 row to the end, there's a lot code that I don't know why it is here.

In the end, I have two questions:

1) Why is it produced that code?

2) Is there a way to produce the raw machine code from C without that useless stuff?

Comment: You are looking at inefficient code generated when you don't enable optimizations. When compiling _C_ you could try to pass `-O3` . The first part of the code generated is typical stack frame prologue and then it allocates space on the stack for local variables.

Comment: Inserting the option for optimization of course it does not generate the stack frame prologue, however it still does generate the code after the RET that has not matching with the main function.

Comment: The stuff after the function is likely exception handling information. I didn't look at it closely. It really isn't code but data. You could try building with _GCC_ using `-fno-exceptions` and see what happens

Comment: You'd want to write a linker script for your kernel. The succeeding "code" is not code, as is obvious by the number of `0000`. Also, I am not sure if `-m elf` makes sense at all since your kernel is not an elf file.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : The _LD_ option `-m elf_i386` would have been needed (in the case where he wasn't using a 32-bit cross compiler) since his environment would have likely been 64-bit. Specifying `elf_i386` would have forced the linker to interpret `kernel.o` as a 64-bit object instead of a 32-bit one. This is required even though the output ends up binary.

Comment: As for the code itself, it is rather OK, if you want to debug the kernel, you'd want to have the frame pointer... :D

Comment: I inserted this option in the first try before using a cross compiler (because my environment is 64-bit). Of course, when I used the cross compiler that is targeted for 32-bit, I did not use it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: This is not C++. C does not support exceptions.

Comment: The other possibility for that data is that it is part of the `comment` section.

Comment: @Olaf, although _C_ doesn't, _GCC_ will often still create an `.eh_frame` section in the object. I usually use a linker script to discard the `.eh_frame` section and the `comment` section(as well as the build notes).

Comment: What GCC you are using? I tried your code and it works fine - binary is 21 bytes. Also rename main() to _start() to eliminate warning.

Comment: I usually do this with a linker script but you should also be able to get rid of the `.comment` and `.eh_frame` sections with _OBJCOPY_ by having the linker output to ELF, strip the sections in question and then convert the ELF to a binary file. Something like (assuming an i686 cross compiler) `i686-elf-ld -Ttext 0x1000 kernel.o -m elf_i386 -o kernel.elf`
`i686-elf-objcopy --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.eh_frame kernel.elf kernel.elf`
`i686-elf-objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin`

Comment: By chance were you using a 64-bit Ubuntu 16.10 (or later) release?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10. Why?

Comment: I was trying to understand your environment. In 64-bit Ubuntu 16.10 the default for _GCC_ on that platform is to build executables with position independent code. Had you done this on 16.04 or earlier you would have likely found you wouldn't have had to disable PIC and you wouldn't have got the error `undefined reference to '_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hints first:

- avoid naming your starting routine `main`. It is confusing (both for the reader and perhaps for the compiler; when you don't pass `-ffreestanding` to `gcc` it is handling `main` very specifically). Use something else like `start` or `begin_of_my_kernel` ...
- compile with `gcc -v`  to understand what your particular compiler is doing.
- you probably should ask your compiler for *some* optimizations and *all* warnings, so pass `-O -Wall` at least to `gcc`
- you may want to look into the produced assembler code, so use `gcc -S -O -Wall -fverbose-asm kernel.c` to get the `kernel.s` assembler file and glance into it
- as commented by [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) you might want to pass `-fno-exceptions`
- your probably need some [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html) and/or some hand-written assembler for [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)
- you should read something about [linkers & loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

---

> ```
>  kernel.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to '_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
> ```

This smells like something related to [position-independent-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). My guess: try compiling with an [*explicit* `-fno-pic` or `-fno-pie`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)

<sup>(on *some* Linux distributions, their `gcc` *might* be configured with some `-fpic` enabled by default)</sup>

PS. Don't forget to add `-m32` to `gcc` if you want x86 32 bits binaries.

Comment: I'm your upvote. I also provided an example in my last comment using OBJCOPY instead of a linker script. Linker script is my preference of course but there is always more than one way to skin the cat.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. With the -fno-pic option I can compile directly with my gcc without using the cross-compiler gcc I made. However, even passing the option -fno-exceptions, If I disassembly from the binary I had the same useless code after the RET. With the procedure proposed by @Michael Petch it worked fine! Thanks also to you

Comment: @gyro91 : If you are going to work on a toy OS over the long term I highly recommend you stick with a cross compiler. It will save you hassles and grief in the long run. The useless code is actually data being interpreted as instructions by _NDISASM_ because in a binary file it can't properly distinguish between code and data that has been lumped together.

Comment: @Michael Petch: Actually I am working with a cross compiler. I used OBJCOPY as you suggested and it worked fine!